# Artemis SOCKS Proxy Support

Tags: java, socks, activemq-artemis

[SOCKS proxy support](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/release-notes-2.12.0) was released in 2.12.0. Here is the [PR](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/pull/1293) of the feature. However, I'm not able to setup Artemis SOCKS proxy using the following:

```java
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(TransportConstants.HOST_PROP_NAME, "localhost");
params.put(TransportConstants.PORT_PROP_NAME, "61617"); //<acceptor name="netty">tcp://0.0.0.0:61617</acceptor>
params.put(TransportConstants.PROXY_ENABLED_PROP_NAME, "true");
params.put(TransportConstants.PROXY_HOST_PROP_NAME, "localhost");
params.put(TransportConstants.PROXY_PORT_PROP_NAME, "1080");
params.put(TransportConstants.PROXY_USERNAME_PROP_NAME, "user");
params.put(TransportConstants.PROXY_PASSWORD_PROP_NAME, "WRONG_PASSWORD");

TransportConfiguration transportConfiguration = new TransportConfiguration("org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory", params);
ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = ActiveMQJMSClient.createConnectionFactoryWithoutHA(JMSFactoryType.CF, transportConfiguration);
```

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
  <artifactId>artemis-jms-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is ignoring the proxy configuration. Even passing the wrong proxy configuration like non-existent host, password, and username the message is successfully sent to the broker. This doesn't fail. It seems those `PROXY_*` properties are not being loaded.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "This is ignoring the proxy conf"? How do you know it's being ignored?

Comment: Thank you. Even passing wrong proxy configuration like wrong host, password, and username, the message is successfully sent to the broker. It seems those PROXY_* properties are not being loaded.

Comment: Was it supposed to fail, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `localhost` the proxy settings are ignored. See [the code](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/2.14.0/artemis-core-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/remoting/impl/netty/NettyConnector.java#L567) for reference. Therefore, you should use a non-loopback IP or hostname when configuring proxy support.

Also, just so you know you can use a URL instead of the `TransportConfiguration`, e.g.:

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory =  new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://non_loopback_ip:61617?socksEnabled=true;socksHost=localhost;socksPort=1080;socksUsername=user;socksPassword=WRONG_PASSWORD");
```

Comment: FWIW, I just sent [a commit](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/commit/87274675d6172235805210278896d2138f2bb6ec) to update the docs with config details.